# OrientDB Find vertex containing relationship to anther vertex without further relationship

Tags: orientdb

I have found similar questions but nothing has really worked for me yet so I'm hoping for a fresh answer.

I have a graph but let me simplify the problem here.  I have three classes (Warehouse, Product, Item).  A warehouse is where products are made.  A Product is a definition of something.  And item is an instance of a product we track as inventory.

The relationships look something like this.
Warehouse->[produces]->Product->[created]->Item

I am trying to find all Warehouses that have a Product that have no Items.  Is this possible in the SQL syntax?  If not is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

If you've modeled it using Graph API you can do something like:

```
select from Warehouse where out('produces').out('created').size() == 0
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.  It returns a weird number of results that doesn't match my expectations at all.

Anyways, I have gotten this working in gremlin.